# Compare month of year enum with datetime month

Tags: c#, datetime, enumeration

I have enum:

```
public enum MonthsOfTheYear
{
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 4,
    April = 8,
    May = 16,
    June = 32,
    July = 64,
    August = 128,
    September = 256,
    October = 512,
    November = 1024,
    December = 2048,
    AllMonths = 4095,
}
```

and Datime.Now.Month.

For example if value of month is 5 it equals "May", how I can compare with the month enum? 
This example not work:
if (!monthsOfYear.Any(x=>x.Code.Equals((MonthsOfTheYear)(1 << (currentDateTime.Month - 1)))

Comment: `if (DateTime.Now.Month == 5) return MonthsOfTheYear.May`?

Comment: Why are you downvoting everyones helpful answers?

Comment: @danrichardson: Why are you assuming that the OP is downvoting the answers?

Comment: Well if it's yourself, based on your comment below, it still doesn't mean the answer is "not helpful", because they are. This question has nothing to do with the most optimal way of processing a single statement, merely how.

Comment: @danrichardson: Answers which lead people to use bad programming techniques are actively harmful except insofar as when downvoted they hopefully become *examples of what not to do*. By downvoting examples of bad programming techniques we make the internet better and increase the spread of knowledge of proper techniques.

Comment: @user2382193: FYI your enum does not follow the standard good programming practice for flags enums of (1) marking the enum with the `[Flags]` attribute, and (2) supporting a `None` value equal to zero. Please consider doing so.

Comment: @EricLippert it also works both ways though. If you have a team of average developers, there is no point having code which no-one understands as it makes it unmaintainable. It's not necessarily "bad" programming techniques, just not the best way to do it. But then the "best" way to do something can always vary slightly depending on how intense and how many times a block of code needs to be ran. There is a fine balance between what is required to do, how to do it, and then how someone can understand the code that is written to do said job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit of a strange way to represent a month, but it is not difficult to do what you want.

The operator you need is the *left bit shift operator*, `<<`. If you imagine a number as a string of bits, say

```
0000 0000 1111 0000  (240 in binary)
```

then the bit shift operators shift them some number of places to the left or right; shifting left one would be

```
0000 0001 1110 0000  (480 in binary)
```

In your case, January is the bit 1 shifted left zero times, February is the bit 1 shifted left one time, and so on:

```
int may = 5;
MonthsOfTheYear result = (MonthsOfTheYear)(1 << (may - 1));
```

Make sense?

UPDATE:

> What is wrong with this code?
>
> ```
> !monthsOfYear.Any(x=>x.Code.Equals((MonthsOfTheYear)(1 << (currentDateTime.Month - 1)))))
> ```
>
> where monthsOfYear is 1 + 2 + 4 + 8  ?

You have the number 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 which is 15. That is not *equal* to 1, 2, 4 or 8.  You don't want equality in the first place.

To test whether a flag is set, use the `&` operator.

Let's make this easier to understand by abstracting away into a helper method:

```
// Is bit "flag" set in bit field "flags"?
static bool IsFlagSet(int flags, int flag)
{
    return (flags & (1 << flag)) != 0;
}
```

Make sure you understand how that works. If you have flags

```
0000 0011
```

And you ask if flag 1 is set then it shifts the bit 1 to the left by 1 place:

```
0000 0010
```

And then says "give me 1 if both corresponding bits are set, zero otherwise."  So that's

```
0000 0010
```

That is not zero, so the flag must have been set.

Now you can say:

```
bool result = IsFlagSet((int)monthsOfYear, currentDateTime.Month - 1);
```

This gives you true if that flag was set, false otherwise.

Make sense?

Comment: If you're going to use this route I would recommend bit shifting the enum values so you don't have a mash of programming techniques. I think it's something like `January << 0, February << 1, etc..`

Comment: user2382193, I think you'll find everyone's answer here worked. You should not be down voting answers for no reason.

Comment: @danrichardson: Most of these answers are either extremely slow compared to bit shifting or wrong. There is plenty of reason to downvote these answers. The user is attempting to *manipulate a bit vector*, so `Math.Pow` is completely the wrong choice; it is intended for computing *powers of real numbers*, not manipulating bit fields. It is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Sorry, I need compare this code if (!monthsOfYear.Any(x=>x.Code.Equals((MonthsOfTheYear)(1 << (currentDateTime.Month - 1))))) return true;  but x.Code have 1,2,4,8

Comment: I agree with @danrichardson - There are different ways to skin a cat and good to have several answers as you are not sure exactly what OP is always aiming for. Down voting all of them seems to defeat point of asking for help! I've removed my answer as there are plenty doing the same thing. Shame Eric seems to think there is only one path.

Comment: @Belogix: All the other answers to this question are bad ideas.

Comment: @Belogix There is more to consider for an answer than just whether or not it works.  That mindset will result in you creating lots of unmaintainable code that is hard to work with, understand, or modify.  It's appropriate to use code that is semantically correct as well as technically correct in this field, unless there is a particularly compelling reason not to.

Comment: @user2382193: I've updated my answer to address your second question.

Comment: @EricLippert - Did you just reimplement [`Enum.HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx)?

Comment: @MattJohnson: Almost but not quite. Enum.HasFlag takes the flag, not its bit position, and it, unfortunately, boxes its argument. But yes, I was remiss in not mentioning it.

Comment: EricLippert, your second update It's work, Thank you very much

Comment: Nice full answer though @EricLippert